# Calling a function with all elements in an array as parameters

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a function

```
function xyz ($var1, $var2) {
  // do stuff
}
```

and an array

```
$array = ['foo', 'bar' ...];
```

Now I want to pass all of the the array's elements into the function as individual parameters.

How can I do this automatically?

I could of course do this

```
$rfc = new ReflectionFunction('xyz');
$argCount = $rfc->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
switch ($argCount) {
  case 1:
    xyz(array[0]);
  break;

  case 2:
    xyz($array[0], $array[1]);
  break;

  ...
}
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP >=5.6, You can actually use [variadic arguments (the splat operator)](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list), and the additional parameters will be ignored if they're not used in the function.

```
xyz(...$array);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't even know this existed!